# How can I install a headless JDK on an Ubuntu Jaunty server?

Tags: ubuntu, headless, java

I recently set up a build server that requires a JDK to run (for example, to compile the Java sources). The OpenJDK package in Ubuntu pulls in the OpenJDK JRE as a dependency which, in turn, depends on a large number of packages that are only relevant for graphical environments. For the standard JRE, there's a headless version of the package, but for the JDK, no.

This issue has been discussed in various places before, and one solution that I found and used was this:

```
$ apt-get --no-install-recommends -d install openjdk-6-jdk
$ dpkg -i --ignore-depends=openjdk-6-jre /path/to/just-downloaded.deb
```

While this worked, it now leaves my system with a broken dependency tree and apt-get refuses further installs untill I run `apt-get -f`.

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed in the following [ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/257857).

As far as I can see you have the following options:

1. Use the non-free Java JDK from Sun. (You can use the [JavaPackage](http://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) program from debian/ubuntu to create a deb pacakge of the non-free java JDK).
2. Work with ubuntu developers to solve this issue.
3. Create your own OpenJDK-headless package.

Of course, option 2 is the best in the long term, as it solves the problem for everyone, and options 1 and 3 solve it only for you, however 1 and 3 are quicker.

Comment: That bug thread does not look very promising to me. It seems there are some side effects to be tackled and the maintainer seems not too eager about solving the problem. I'll probably be selfish and go for the Sun JDK.

Comment: What should I do to implement option 3? See http://serverfault.com/questions/755573 for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just download and install Sun's JDK? No compiling, no X11 required. I prefer it to the packaged options.

```
chmod +x ~/jdk-6u14-linux-i586.bin
cd /usr
sudo mkdir java
cd java
sudo ~/jdk-6u14-linux-i586.bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_14
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect he just needed to update his etc-alternatives links:

```
update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
```

(or something like that)