# How to create a headless JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, ubuntu-14.04, headless

I want to have a headless JDK on Ubuntu 14.04. As discussed in the question [“How can I install a headless JDK on an Ubuntu Jaunty server?”](https://serverfault.com/questions/46946), one option is to create my own jdk-headless package.

I have tried to create a dummy package using equivs:

```
Section: java
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: openjdk-7-jre-dummy4headless
Maintainer: ...
Depends: java7-runtime-headless
Provides: openjdk-7-jre
Description: fake package to allow us to use java7-runtime-headless instead of openjdk-7-jre for some small tools
```

However, this does not seem to satisfy the dependencies, i.e., when installing openjdk-7-jdk, it still wants to install openjdk-7-jre, even with this dummy package installed.

What should I modify to fix this?

Comment: I've since moved to 16.04 and the issue is moot for me now.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `openjdk-7-jdk-headless` package through apt, which will give you a full OpenJDK7 headless JDK with one step.

Here is the package's page on ubuntu.com: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openjdk-7-jre-headless